# Is there a way, in a nodejs microservices application, to share the mongoose initialization code?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, microservices

So I am building a microservice application and I would like to share some common functions to a central package - commons, and then reuse this code across the other services.

The folder structure looks like the following:

```
/services
  /commons
  /service1
  /service2
```

Every one of the folder under services, in this example, is a package with separated package.json and so on.

I've been testing if mongoose works that way - I put the initialization code into the commons package and then imported it into the service1. As a result, the initialization went through correctly and the connection has been establish but, when I try to save some documents I have a timeout error.

My mongoose version is: 7.2.4.

Have anybody already face this issue? how do you share the initialization of mongoose into different services so that it works?

I've tried with the mongoose initialization into the package commons - does not work.
I've tried with mongoose directly initialized (the file for the initialization and so on ) into the service - does work.`

Comment: I think you can use Singleton class for connection, so when the connection is initiated from anywhere, same database instance is used inside other services. and can you tell, does write operation only fails or reading too?